# Check balance of an address by Monero RPC

Tags: monerod, rpc, address, monero-wallet-rpc, balance

In monero RPC, to consult the balance of a wallet we used the following command:
"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getbalance"}"

How then we will do to consult the balance of an address belonging to this wallet ?
Can you help me please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `per_subaddress` field of the result returned by the `get_balance` method contains the balances of the addresses.
There is also the `get_accounts` method that gives the balance for each account.

Documentation:

- [get_balance](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#getbalance)
- [get_accounts](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_accounts)